# cassandra node to node encryption throws unable to gossip with peers exception

Tags: cassandra

We currently run a multi region cassandra cluster in AWS.  It runs in four regions, 12 nodes per region.  It runs without node to node encryption (or client encryption either).  We are trying to enable inter datacenter node to node encryption.  However, when we flip encryption over we get an exception that nodes are `unable to gossip with any peers.`

It could possibly be that we didn't build our jks keystore/truststores correctly (more on how we built these files below).  But, we additionally do not see intra datacenter communication working (which should be set to unencrypted communication).  Additionally, cqlsh cannot connect to the node either; even though we have (by default) `client_auth_required` set to `false`.

```
ERROR [main] 2019-08-15 18:46:32,241 CassandraDaemon.java:749 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1435) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:566) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:823) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:683) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:632) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:388) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
INFO  [main] 2019-08-15 18:47:07,384 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Something to note is that this error message occurs after a few minutes of the node being up. (i.e. there is a delay between start up before this exception is thrown).

**Information about our cassandra setup**

cassandra version: 3.11.4
JDK version: openjdk-8.
Linux: Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic).

***cassandra.yaml***

```
endpoint_snitch: Ec2MultiRegionSnitch

server_encryption_options:
  internode_encryption: dc
  keystore: <omitted>
  keystore_password: <omitted>
  truststore: <omitted>
  truststore_password: <omitted>

client_encryption_options:
  enabled: false
```

***cassandra-rackdc.properties***

```
prefer_local=true
```

**No obvious errors with SSH output**

When starting cassandra with `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"` added to `cassandra-env.sh` we see SSL logs printed to stdout (*Note: Subject and Issuer were omitted on purpose)*.

```
found key for : cassy-us-west-2                                                                                                                                                                                                       
adding as trusted cert:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  Subject: ...                                                                                                                                                      
  Issuer:  ...                                                                                                                                                      
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xdad28d843fc73325d4c1a75207d4e74                                                                                                                                                                    
  Valid from Fri May 27 00:00:00 UTC 2016 until Tue May 26 23:59:59 UTC 2026  

...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
```

Looking at [Java SE SSL/TLS connection debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), this looks correct.  But to note, we see this series of messages (along with the RSA key signature output) repeated several times in rapid fire.  We never observe any messages about the trust store being added; however that might be something that occurs only on client initiation (?)

Additionally, we do see cassandra report that the Encrypted Messaging service has been started.

```
INFO  [main] 2019-08-15 18:45:31,022 MessagingService.java:704 - Starting Encrypted Messaging Service on SSL port 7001
```

**Doesn't appear to be a cassandra.yaml configuration problem**

We can bring the node back online by simply configuring `internode_encryption: none`.  This action seems to rule out a broadcast_address or rpc_address configuration problem.

**How we built our keystore/truststores**

We followed the basic template datastax docs for [preparing SSL certificates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLCertWithCA.html).  One minor difference was that our private key and CSRs were generated using `openssl`.  One per each region (we plan to share key/signed certs across nodes in regions).  This was created using a command template as:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -out cassy-<region>.csr -keyout cassy-<region>.key -config cassy-<region>.conf -subj "..." -nodes -sha256
```

The generated CSR was then signed by an internal root CA.  Because we generated our files using openssl, we had to build our jks files by importing our certs into them.

***Commands to generate truststore***

We distribute this one file to all nodes.

```
keytool -importcert 
    -keystore generic-server-truststore.jks 
    -alias rootCa  
    -file rootCa.crt 
    -noprompt
    -keypass omitted 
    -storepass omitted
```

***Commands to generate keystore***

This was done one per region; but essentially we created a keystore with keytool, then deleted the key entry and then imported our key entry using keytool from a pkcs12 file.

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias cassy-${region} -keystore cassy-${region}.jks -storepass omitted -keypass omitted -validity 365 -keysize 2048 -dname "..." 

keytool -delete -alias cassy-${region} -keystore cassy-${region}.jks -storepass omitted

openssl pkcs12 -export -in signed_certs/${region}.pem -inkey keys/cassandra.${region}.key -name cassy-${region} -out ${region}.p12 

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass omitted -destkeystore cassy-${region}.jks -srckeystore ${region}.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 

keytool -importcert -keystore cassy-${region}.jks -alias rootCa -file ca.crt -noprompt -keypass omitted -storepass omitted
```

Looking back at this, I don't remember why we used keytool to generate a keypair/keystore, then deleted and imported.  I think it was because the keytool importkeystore command refused to run if the keystore didn't already exist.

***ca.crt and pem file***

The `ca.crt` file contains the root certificate and the intermediate certificate that was used to sign the CSR.  The pem file contains the signed CSR returned to us, the intermediate cert, and the root CA (in that order).

***openssl verify ca.crt and pem***

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt us-west-2.pem
signed_certs/us-west-2.pem: OK
```

**Command output after enabling encryption**

***`nodetool status` (output truncated)***

```
Datacenter: us-east                                                                                                
===================                                      
Status=Up/Down                                           
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving                   
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
?N  52.44.11.221    ?          256          25.4%             null                                  1c             
...
?N  52.204.232.195  ?          256          23.2%             null                                  1d             
Datacenter: us-west-2                                                                                              
=====================
Status=Up/Down                                           
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving                   
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack           
?N  34.209.2.144    ?          256          26.5%             null                                  2c             
UN  52.40.32.177    105.99 GiB  256          23.7%             null                                  2c            
?N  34.210.109.203  ?          256          24.7%             null                                  2a   
...
```

With the online node being the node with encryption set.

***`cqlsh` to localhost***

```
cassy-node6:~$ cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

***`cqlsh` to remote node***
Remote node is a node with encryption enabled

```
cassy-node6:~$ cqlsh 10.0.2.7
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.2.7': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('10.0.2.7', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

**Behavior we expected**

We expected for the node to report that the other regions were all down, as they need to be handled over encryption.  So that works as expected; however, cqlsh and intra datacenter peers being reported as unreachable is unexpected.

Specifically, we expected the node to still show peer nodes within the same datacenter as up and normal, regardless if there is a cert issue/error.  We also expected `cqlsh` to continue to work.

Lastly, we are also trying to figure out if we have a jks certificate problem.

Comment: I have a document that I put together regarding encryption (TDE, client traffic, and node-to-node). If you're interested in it, I can send it to a valid e-mail address. You can check it out to see if anything sticks out. We use DSE, but I'm thinking it should be portable if you're not. Let me know. I had a few tickets opened with Datastax when I first tried getting this working. I think I hit similar issues. Again, maybe it will help, maybe not. Let me know and I'll send it over to you. -Jim

Comment: @JimWartnick I would be interested in looking at your notes regarding encryption.  We don't use DSE, but my guess is that there shouldn't be much difference regarding encryption setup.  My email address is mcarlise@salesforce.com.  After looking at it, I'll let you know if it helped or not.  Thanks

Comment: I have sent you a copy of our documentation. Hope it helps.